# opencv python3 merge acting weird

Tags: python-3.x, merge, opencv3.0

I have been trying to find answer for hours for this strange behavior of cv2.merge().

In short, I'm merging 3 images of uint8 1-channel with size of 960x1280, gets a merged image of 960x1280x3,
but each channel is 1280x3 instead of 960x1280.

As a result, I can't plot it.

I'm loading each image using:

```
        img = cv2.imread(file).astype(np.uint8)
        if len(img.shape) > 2:  img = img[:,:,1]
```

Here is the code for merging (with additional information):

```
alg = (img1,img2,img3)
print('type: ',type(alg[0]),type(alg[1]),type(alg[2]))
print('dtype: ',alg[0].dtype, alg[1].dtype, alg[2].dtype)
print('shape: ',alg[0].shape, alg[1].shape, alg[2].shape)

PseudoRGB = cv2.merge(alg)
print('\nmerged type: ',type(PseudoRGB))
print('merged dtype: ',PseudoRGB.dtype)
print('merged shape: ',PseudoRGB.shape)
print('merged shape, each channel: ',PseudoRGB[0].shape, PseudoRGB[1].shape, PseudoRGB[2].shape)
```

That gives me:

```
type:  <class 'numpy.ndarray'> <class 'numpy.ndarray'> <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
dtype:  uint8 uint8 uint8
shape:  (960, 1280) (960, 1280) (960, 1280)

merged type:  <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
merged dtype:  uint8
merged shape:  (960, 1280, 3)
merged shape, each channel:  (1280, 3) (1280, 3) (1280, 3)
```

Any help is much appreciated.